# Can ServiceStack parse similar routes?

Tags: servicestack

I've got the following routes that i want defined in my app:

```
/s/customers/1234/summary
```

and

```
/s/locations/5767/summary
```

now normally i would define my route like so:

```
Add<CustomerSummaryRequest>("/s/customers/{Id}/summary")
Add<LocationSummaryRequest>("/s/locations/{Id}/summary")
```

However the problem is, the id for customer and location in my DB, itself is

```
/customers/1234
/locations/5767
```

And would ultimately like to have these routes:

```
Add<CustomerSummaryRequest>("/s/{CustomerId*}/summary")
Add<LocationSummaryRequest>("/s/{LocationId*}/summary")
```

Any suggestions?

I realize i could do:

```
Add<CustomerSummaryRequest>("/s/Customers/{CustomerId*}/summary")
Add<LocationSummaryRequest>("/s/Locations/{LocationId*}/summary")
```

which will give me the numeric portion of the id. and then I could just combine the id with either customers/ or /locations/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have ambiguous routes in ServiceStack so either you can either have a catch all Request that handles both requests and routes to the appropriate Service, e.g:

```
[Route("/s/{Id*}/summary")]
public class SummaryRequest 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public object Any(SummaryRequest request)
{
    var id = "/" + request.Id;
    return request.Id.StartsWith("customers/")
        ? Gateway.Send(new CustomerSummaryRequest { CustomerId = id })
        : Gateway.Send(new LocationSummaryRequest { LocationId = id });
}
```

Or you have unique routes for different Services, e.g:

```
[Route("/s/customers/{CustomerId}/summary")]
public class CustomerSummaryRequest 
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}


[Route("/s/locations/{LocationId}/summary")]
public class CustomerSummaryRequest 
{
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
}
```

And construct your Id in your Service.

Comment: The prob with the first approach is you have a Summary Request and it isn't clear when looking at the MetaData View what Id is supposed to have.

The prob with the second approach is the route signature looks off: /s/locations/{LocationId}/summary in which case the locationId is actually locations/1234. 

Any plans on providing Regex based routes, or the ability to "intercept" a particular incoming request and dynamically determine its Request Message ?

Comment: @legion If we allowed RegEx route matching we wouldn't be able to statically determine the best matching route without evaluating each Regex which would hurt performance and break Reverse Routing. You can try using a Request Converter which lets you return a different Request DTO to execute a different Service.